# Why symbol "№" in text is bolder than others characters?

Tags: html, typography

Example of view. Symbol "№" looks bolder than other charaсters:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij9ae.png

How make it thinner?

Comment: Depends on the font you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your font probably doesn't contain this character, so it takes it from an other one, try changing font.